# C# Создание классов

Tags: c#

Ребят, привет. У меня вопрос насчёт классов C#. 
У меня есть файл Character.cs, в котором я создаю класс.

```
public class Character
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Позже в основном файле в классе Создания персонажа я записываю сюда данные:

```
Character.Character character = new Character.Character
    {
      Name = CharacterController.LoadCharacterData(player).Result[0].Name,
      Surname = CharacterController.LoadCharacterData(player).Result[0].Surname
    };
```

Данные берутся из БД. В другом файле я записывал данные в БД

```
public static bool CreateCharacter(Client player, string name, string surname)
{
  Character.Character character = new Character.Character
  {
    Name = name,
    Surname = surname
  };

  Characters.InsertOneAsync(character);
  return false;
}
```

И теперь я хочу записать эти данные(о персонаже) в глобальные переменные и чтобы я мог их использовать в любой части кода/в любом файле. Если что-то не так объяснил - спросите. Отвечу в комментариях.

Comment: Глобальные переменные- зло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Это плохая идея. Это противоречит идеологии ООП
2. Но ты это можешь сделать если обьявишь переменные Character статическими.

Comment: Не могу сделать static, потому что при создании нового Персонажа жалуется на переменную Name/Surname ,что они статические.

Comment: так не делай нейм и сурнейм статическими, делай инстанс Character-а статическим.

Comment: а если нужен список Character-ов что бы был доступным отовсюду... так и создай public static List<character>

Answer (score 1):

Глобальные переменные - это зло.

Лучше сделать специализированные классы для работы с твоим классом и передавать `Character` как аргумент.

Да, придется много передавать переменные туда сюда, но каждый класс будет самодостаточным.

Comment: Можешь показать пример или скинуть где я могу с этим ознакомиться поподробнее? Я уже немного помучался с конструктором, в котором передавал character и у меня ничего не вышло. Сейчас заново пытаюсь.

Comment: Да просто, создай вспомогательные классы и передавай им в конкструктор свой класс и работай. Ничего сверхестественного.